# Windows 10, VS 2013: Cmake error while configuring OpenCL program

Tags: cmake, opencl

I'm trying to build this [Github project](https://github.com/sat8/YoloOCLInference) in Windows. Getting the error below. I've installed the AMD SDK and added the path to PATH variable. Please let me know how to overcome this issue.

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:94 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindOpenCL.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCL", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCL" with any
  of the following names:

    OpenCLConfig.cmake
    opencl-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "OpenCL" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "OpenCL_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "OpenCL"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: According to docs, CMake provides `FindOpenCL.cmake` module since version 3.1. Which CMake version do you use?

Comment: Thank you. I was having cmake 2.8, after upgrade it worked perfectly.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Please write your comment as an answer, I will mark it and let this question be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to docs, CMake provides `FindOpenCL.cmake` module since version 3.1. So you need at least CMake 3.1 for build given project.

---

Actually, it is the project's `cmake_minimum_required` who should provide correct constraint.